# Nhibernate sum/groupby question

Tags: nhibernate

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OrderHistory](
    [RecordID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserID] [int] NOT NULL, /* FK to user table*/
    [ItemID] [int] NOT NULL, /* FK to Item table */
    [PurchaseDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [UnitPrice] [money] NOT NULL,
    [Quantity] [float] NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [RecordID] ASC
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I have a table to save order history of users. I need to calculate total money spent by a user on yearly basis. If I write SQL query directly, it is very simple and straightforward:

```
select SUM(UnitPrice * Quantity) as TotalAmount, DATEPART(yyyy, PurchaseDate)
from OrderHistory
where UserId = 1
group by DATEPART(yyyy, PurchaseDate)
```

Planned object model is:

```
public class YearlySummary {
        public virtual int Year {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public virtual decimal TotalSpent {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
```

But how can I do it in Nhibernate?

Thanks
Hardy

Comment: NHibernate queries work on an object model, not on the DB model. What is your object model?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using Linq.

You should be doing something as follows:

from orderHistory in Session.Linq.Where(x=>x.UserId=1) group by orderHistory.PurchaseDate into g select new {TotalAmount=g.Sum(orderHistory.UnitPrice * orderHistory.Quantity)}

Comment: Do you mean LinqToSql? But I have to use NHibernate framework. I could not find Linq under ISession interface.

Comment: @hardywang, Linq to NHibernate is a separate project that you probably want anyway. http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/07/26/nhibernate-linq-1.0-released.aspx for 2.1; not sure about Nhibernate 3.0. Otherwise, you can use the ICriteria interface for programmatically build group-by queries, or HQL for ones that are unlikely to change (other than parameters).

Comment: @hardywang - if you're using NH3.0 then you use .Query<T>, NH3.0 has it's own LINQ provider, 2.1 has a 3rd party LINQ provider.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have to fetch the (historic) data it's quite easy actually. Use a formula in your mapping file:

```
<property name="TotalSpent" formula="UnitPrice * Quantity" type="Decimal" />
```

This will multiply the two values in the query (e.g. select UnitPrice * Quantity from OrderHistory) and put the result in the TotalSpent property. Note that this won't work for transient objects until you persist the data.